# Have I gone about this proof in a clear way?

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity

Prove that if $f$ is *uniformly** continuous on a bounded set $S \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is a bounded function on $S$.

Assume that $f$ is not continuous on a bounded set $S \in \mathbb{R}$. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $f$ has a convergent subsequence because it is bounded. Since $f$ is bounded and has a convergent subsequence, it must be Cauchy. That is,

$$f(x_{n_k}) \to L \implies x_{n_k} \to L_0$$

Since $x_{n_k}$ is Cauchy, it must be continuous, which is a contradiction to our assumption.  $\square$

* corrected

Comment: Isn't $1/x$ on $(0,1]$ a counterexample?

Comment: Ah shoot. I see my mistake. It's meant to be uniformly continuous. Based on what I posted, yes, that would be a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you are trying to prove that $f$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then why did you start with the statement $f$ is not continuous on a bounded set $S$?